# py2exe cannot find a module

Tags: python, py2exe, configobj

I have a Python app that works fine. Now I use py2exe to create a windows executable of this app, however the resulting exe fails with complain that it lacks the [configobj](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html) module

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file1.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "file2.pyc", line 10, in <module>
ImportError: No module named configobj
```

Line 10 in file2.py is merely `from configobj import ConfigObj`

I tried to explicitly add configobj to the list of packed modules by specifying `-i configobj` argument, but then the py2exe run fails with the similar error:

```
running py2exe
creating  C:\path\to\proj\dist
*** generate typelib stubs ***
collected 0 stubs from 1 type libraries
*** searching for required modules ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File " C:\path\to\proj\py2exe_setup.py", line 18, in <module>
    options = {"py2exe": {"typelibs": [('{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}', 0, 1, 5)]}},
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 243, in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 296, in _run
    self.find_needed_modules(mf, required_files, required_modules)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1297, in find_needed_modules
    mf.import_hook(mod)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 136, in import_hook
    q, tail = self.find_head_package(parent, name)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 204, in find_head_package
    raise ImportError, "No module named " + qname
ImportError: No module named configobj
```

The configobj module is installed on my computer in its default location

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79096, Mar 19 2010, 21:48:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import configobj
>>> print configobj.__version__
4.7.2
>>> import py2exe
C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py:16: DeprecationWarning: the sets module is deprecated
  import sets
>>> print py2exe.__version__
0.6.9
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling configobj from source fixed the problem. Damn me if I know why